# Polymer 1.0 styling in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, polymer

I'm playing with Polymer 1.0 by creating a simple custom-element (ui-button).

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="ui-button">
    <link rel="import" type="css" href="ui-button.css">
    <template>
        <button class="ui button">
            <template is="dom-if" if="{{icon}}"><i class="icon">1</i></template>
            <template is="dom-if" if="{{label}}">{{label}}</template>
        </button>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script src="ui-button.js"></script>
```

Everything works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox the button has no styling.
My guess is that the problem is the external stylesheet, because when i put the CSS inline (style-tag)...it works.

Is this a bug in Polymer 1.0?
I really want to use the external stylesheet...

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html says it's currently an "experimental feature", so I suspect it is a bug. Alternatively, I would try putting your CSS in a separate file with `<style>` tags and import that as a regular HTML import, no `type="css"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in both Chrome and Firefox. This is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet.css">

    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="/app/general/your-element.html">
  </head>

<body>
    <your-element></your-element>
</body>

</html>
```

Inside the element, I'm using the css class / id references just like you would on any regular html tag. So, inside of `your-element` looks something like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">    
<dom-module id="your-element">

<template>
<span class="some_class_style">Hey, I'm stylish!</span>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'your-element',
  ...
});
</script>

</dom-module>
```

And, it's styled by whatever you defined for `some_class_style`. Keep in mind, I've only made elements that are one level deep (ie. no children elements), but it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yes, but i want the stylesheet to be inlcuded in the Webcomponent. Not in the index.html